# NPE when i test Retrofit API with Kotlin

Tags: android, unit-testing, kotlin, junit

I'm started to learn how to write test and write this one to test my api:

```
class SharedViewModelTest {

    @get:Rule
    val rule = InstantTaskExecutorRule()

    @Mock private lateinit var networkHelper: NetworkHelperImpl
    @Mock private lateinit var employeeInteractor: EmployeeInteractorImpl
    @Mock private lateinit var specialityInteractor: SpecialityInteractorImpl
    @Mock private lateinit var api:ApiService

    private lateinit var sharedViewModel: SharedViewModel

    @Before fun setUp() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this)
        sharedViewModel = SharedViewModel(networkHelper, employeeInteractor, specialityInteractor)
    }

    @Test
    fun `check is json correct`(){
        val result = runBlocking { api.loadData().await().items }
        result shouldNotBe  null
        result.size shouldNotBe 0
    }
}
```

But i have this when i'm trying to run `check is json correct`:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.example.testtask.view.viewmodel.SharedViewModelTest$check is json correct$result$1.invokeSuspend(SharedViewModelTest.kt:38)
    at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.run(Dispatched.kt:233)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.EventLoopImplBase.processNextEvent(EventLoop.kt:116)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.BlockingCoroutine.joinBlocking(Builders.kt:76)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt__BuildersKt.runBlocking(Builders.kt:53)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt.runBlocking(Unknown Source)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt__BuildersKt.runBlocking$default(Builders.kt:35)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt.runBlocking$default(Unknown Source)
    at com.example.testtask.view.viewmodel.SharedViewModelTest.check is json correct(SharedViewModelTest.kt:38)
```

I really can't undersand why i have NPE(not server on thread error, NPE exacly). I commented lines where i comparing results, but it still crushing, so i think it's not about responce, it's something else.

Can someone explain to me please?

I think app level gradle dependences can help:

```
    //Tests
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13-beta-3'
    testImplementation "org.mockito:mockito-inline:2.8.47"
    testImplementation 'org.robolectric:robolectric:4.3'
    testImplementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.3.41'
    testImplementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-test-junit:1.3.41'
    testImplementation "com.nhaarman:mockito-kotlin:1.4.0"
    testImplementation 'org.amshove.kluent:kluent:1.14'
    testImplementation 'android.arch.core:core-testing:1.1.1'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to mock your api response first. For example:

```
@Test
    fun `check is json correct`(){
        val result = runBlocking { 
            whenever(api.loadData()).thenReturn(async {'create your data'})
            api.loadData().await().items 
        }
        result shouldNotBe  null
        result.size shouldNotBe 0
    }
```

Comment: Ty, it works. As i understand, i can't get real response from API to test my function with it?

Comment: You can get the real response but in that case, you have to not mock your `ApiService` and use the real service instead. But it will be more close to the integration test.